# Using awk to split line with multiple string delimiters

Tags: bash, awk

I have a file called pet_owners.txt that looks like:

```
petOwner:Jane,petName:Fluffy,petType:cat
petOwner:John,petName:Oreo,petType:dog
...
petOwner:Jake,petName:Lucky,petType:dog
```

I'd like to use awk to split the file using the delimiters: 'petOwner', 'petName', and 'petType' so that I can extract the pet owners and pet types. My desired output is:

```
Jane,cat
John,dog
...
Jake,dog
```

So far I've tried:

```
awk < pet_owners.txt -F'['petOwner''petName''petType']' '{print $1 $3}'
```

but the result is a bunch of newlines.

Any ideas for how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 6):

```
$ awk -F'[:,]' -v OFS=',' '{print $2,$6}' file
Jane,cat
John,dog
Jake,dog
```

As for why your attempt wasn't working, mainly it's because `[` and `]` in the context of a regular expression are the "bracket expression" delimiters and what goes inside that is a set of characters (which may be individual characters, ranges, lists, and/or classes) so when you wrote:

```
-F'['petOwner''petName''petType']'
```

that would set `FS` to the set of characters `p`, `e`, `t`, etc. not the set of strings `petOwner`, etc. The multiple internal `'`s are canceling each other out as you jump in/out of shell for no reason exactly as if you had written `-F'[petOwnerpetNamepetType]'` given there's no metacharacters in there that the shell would expand.

To set FS to a set of strings (actually regexps so watch out for metachars) would be:

```
-F'petOwner|petName|petType'
```

Answer (score 4):

you can also write the delimiters in this form instead of char set

```
$ awk -F'pet(Owner|Name|Type):' '{print $2,$4}' file

Jane, cat
John, dog

Jake, dog
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also define what a field is, instead of defining what a separator is. For that you use the **FPAT** variable, like this:

```
~ $ awk '{ print $2,$6 }' FPAT="[^,:]+" OFS="," pet_owners.txt
Jane,cat
John,dog
```

That way you're defining as a field everything that is not a *comma* or a *colon*.

Sometimes it makes programs easier.

**OFS** sets the output field separator to a comma.

Comment: You should mention that FPAT is gawk-only.